# Rsync still copying some folders

Tags: backup, directory, rsync

I'm using rsync to backup some files every day and I noticed that some folders already copied continue to be copied (that folders contain files).

```
sudo rsync -ravp --delete /home/administrador/ArquivosAL/ /media/administrador/Seagate\ Expansion\ Drive/Backup
```

Result:

```
sending incremental file list
Auto/Blocos/_Banheiros/
Auto/Blocos/_Components Sampler/
Auto/Blocos/_Cozinhas/
Auto/Blocos/_Dynamic Components Training/
Auto/Blocos/_Elementos urbanos e exteriores/
Auto/Blocos/_Equipamentos eletronicos/
Auto/Blocos/_Equipamentos hospitalares/
Auto/Blocos/_Equipamentos militares/
Auto/Blocos/_Iluminacao/
...
sent 81,136,037 bytes  received 38,000 bytes  1,546,172.13 bytes/sec
total size is 265,416,084,213  speedup is 3,269.72
```

Someone knows why this happen? Thanks.

Comment: Were there changes to those folders as it's a backup mostly likely it did change in content between backups...

Comment: No changes were made to the files in these folders.